# How do I make a php login page actually work?

Tags: php, html, sql, pgadmin

I am having some trouble making my php login page, you know, actually login. I have created a database using sql with some login info and I am trying to display the information grabbed once the user logs in.

For example once the user logs in I want it to say:
"Welcome back [firstname][lastname]
Our records show that your
email address is: [email]
and you last accessed our system: [date accessed]"

and if the user was not found in the database i want it to say 
"Login failed please try again"

So how to I get the code to actually login(it supposed to be self referring too...)

I have tried so many things, 
I have tried:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$res = pg_query($cser,"select* from users where id='$id'and password='$password'");
$result=pg_fetch_array($res);
if($result)
{
    echo "You are login Successfully ";
    header("location:functions.php");   

}
else
{
    echo "failed ";
}
    }
}
```

Ive been watching youtube videos as well but none of them are helpful at all.

```
<center>
<h2>Please log in</h2>
<p>Enter your login ID and password to connect to this system<br/>
</p>
<form name="Input" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
<table border="1" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="10" >
<tr>
<td><strong>Username:</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" name="login" value="" size="20" placeholder="Username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Password:</strong></td>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" size="20" placeholder="**********" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" >
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value = "Login" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p>
Please wait after pressing <strong>Log in</strong>
while we retrieve your records from our database.<br/>
<em>(This may take a few moments)</em>
</p>
<hr/>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my actual form

Comment: now imagine what would happen if someone tried to login with a password like `' OR TRUE; -- `  that's called an **SQL injection attack**. please read up on parameterised statements to secure your database before coding any further. and never store passwords as plain text! `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` are made for this. i also recommend **not** learning programming from youtube videos.

Comment: yeah well my classes teach me nothing so youtube was the next best thing. all i need is for the stupid page to work. everytime i added new code and test it the page goes blank

Comment: maybe change first input `name="id" ` and second input  `name="password" `

Comment: @FranzGleichmann is correct, you should avoid SQL injection attack and the query that you have should be corrected. "select id, name from users where name='$name'and password='$password'. The form doesn't have a field name "id", you should pass username and encrypted password and update the query to avoid SQL injection attack.

Comment: i know i changed the form name to id and it still doesnt work

Comment: Long time don't use PHP, but I see you are getting id and password in your php code, but in your html code are missing both. I think you should change that to `login` and `pass`

Comment: @Dianne what does functions.php contains ? Anyway , remove the statement $result=pg_fetch_array($res); and use if($res){...} and create session variables right on this page . Also besides sql injection , please encrypt the password too , you have opened up the password to any hacker .

Comment: geez yes three people have told me to encrypt the password which i will do once i get the page working, the functions.php contains a connection to database right now <?php
db_connect()
{
  $conn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=slotegraafd_db user=slotegraafd password=100658347");
}
?>

Comment: Excellent tutorial here [link] https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm

Comment: Your query is malformed, you're missing a space between SELECT and *